# How can I fix "JavaFX runtime components are missing" Maven error when I try to run the FormsFX demo in NetBeans 12?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

I am trying to run a Maven FX Application Project in NetBeans 12. The default project runs OK, but when I try to run the demo of FormsFX there is an error:

```
-- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ mavenproject5 ---
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  2.296 s
Finished at: 2020-07-27T22:04:31-04:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject5: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

How can I fix this Maven error?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX removed from standard JDK, so you have to install it for your platform. Please take a look at the getting started guide from openjfx.io: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: I got it and it works fine. the problem is with the demo of FormsFx. I dont  know what is the error